# Create Binary Classifier in Python Tensorflow with Specific Architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

I am new to Tensorflow (with Python) and find the object model to be a little overwhelming. Suppose I want to create a binary classifier using the sigmoid activation function in Tensorflow with the following architecture:
[image]

(in other words, two inputs, a hidden layer with four units, and then an output).

What would be the easiest way to do this in Tensorflow?

Comment: Just follow quick start guide here - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner with corrections to the model

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
    ])

Comment: Thanks, when I train the model and print the weights (using model.get_weights()), I get the following: https://i.imgur.com/uQUqmb5.png
I'm confused; shouldn't there only be twelve weights, as in my image above? Which weights correspond to what?

Comment: There are should be 16 weights. 2 * 4 then 4 * 2 (binary classifier has two, not one). I'm a pytorch guy (reason I used comment instead of answer) so doing guesses here about output: 8 those are weights for input to hidden layer, then 4 values for hidden layer (not sure what those are, though), then 8 weights for hidden layer to classifier, then 2 for classifier (again not sure what are those).